# How can be made that, without silverlight?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins

Do you have any idea about how is made, or how can be made the slide-show from [vertigosoftware.com](http://vertigosoftware.com) but without using a Silverlight technology.

Do you have any idea if that can be made with jQuery? Do you know which jQuery plugin does that?

Many Thanks

Comment: I believe you need to re-word your question, hit the EDIT button. From what you are asking I think you want to have the vetigo site re-done in javascript? jQuery?

Please be more specific, we can't really help if you don't have a well formatted question.

Comment: I don't see any Silverlight content on the homepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about [carousel plugin](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) in jQuery?

Comment: Or the carousel plugin for YUI